# Credentials issue on Windows slave node fetching from Git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I have a RedHat master node and a Windows slave node. Jenkins (v2.46) is installed on the same RedHat box.
I get the exception below running jobs on the windows slave node. Jobs executing on the master node executes with no problems. It's worth saying that this has only started after upgrading (among others) these plugins:

- credentials plugin to v2.1.13
- git client plugin to v2.4.4
- git plugin to v3.3.0
- ssh credentials plugin to v1.13
- ssh slaves plugin to v1.17

I have read a number of similar issues and tried and checked most of the proposed solutions but none seems to solve my problem. 
The solutions I have tried involves checking credentials on the windows box so I have verified these:
I have checked that on the windows machine, I have the .ssh folder with the correct files (and content) in the user home directory of the jenkins user account.
If I manually clone a repository (i.e. use git clone command in Git Bash) on the windows machine, it doesn't ask me for the jenkins credentials and it clones the repository successfully. Both of these make me believe the local credentials isn't the problem.

```
Fetching upstream changes from git@BBB.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Jenkins SSH for cloning from git repositories.
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@BBB.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune --depth=1
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@BBB.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:809)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1076)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1107)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:496)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.matrix.MatrixRun.run(MatrixRun.java:146)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@BBB.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune --depth=1" returned status code 128:
```

I suspect that I've missed a configuration in Jenkins but cant find what. Any help or pointers will be very much appreciated.

Another observation I've made is that jenkins may be having a problem dealing with a workspace with spaces in it. Because if I rename a build from for e.g "First Run" to "First_Run" then this executes fine on the windows node.

Comment: I thought that if you use `git@...` you use the ssh key. If you want to use the credential helper, you have to use `https://...` AND you have to check that local settings do not overwrite coorect global settings.

Comment: Yes I'm using SSH and dont want to use credential helper

Answer (score 1):

Today, I ran into this problem. 
How I managed to resolve this issue after my research is by re-installing the git on Windows slave server without checking the check box for 'Enabling Git Credential Manager' option.

[image]

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This did not solve my **ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'**

Answer (score 0):

Try to set path to your git.exe at "Global tools configuration"

{jenkins_url}/configureTools/

Comment: Will that not be the path to the git.exe on the master node? I'm not sure that will fix the issue on the slave node where the path to the git.exe is different to that of the master.